# Joining first name and last name in one input as two different values

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, search

I am making a search feature, that searches through a JSON object and finds the person you are looking for and displays some information about them, but for now it only works if you search for either the first name of the person or the last name separately. I want the search to be able to find the person even if I type both the first name and the last name in the same text field.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#getValue").click(function(){
                var typed = $("#typedText").val();

                $(function(){
                    $.getJSON('json.json', function(data) {
                        var search = $(data.GetContactsResult).filter(function (i, n) {
                            if (n.FirstName === typed || n.LastName === typed) {
                                return n.LastName 
                            }
                        });
                        console.log(search);

                        for (var i = 0; i < search.length; i++) {
                            alert(search[i].FirstName + " " + search[i].LastName + " " + search[i].MobileNumber + " " + " " +search[i].StateCaption)
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>click function</title>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="typedText">
    <input type="button" id="getValue" value="Type value">
</body>
</html>
```

I'm not that experienced with JavaScript or jQuery so please tell me if my current solution is a mess and can be done better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn your logic around inside the filter.

```
var search = $(data.GetContactsResult).filter(function (i, n) {
    if (typed.indexOf(n.FirstName) !== -1 || typed.indexOf(n.LastName) !== -1) {
        return n.LastName; 
    }
});
```